# How to apply accent colors without affecting other theme and color resources in windows phone 7.8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I have an unlocked hTC HD7 Windows Phone 7.8. I have some basic knowledge regarding building apps for WP7.8. In this unlocked version the developers have added some additional themes which includes 'black' as an accent color. When applying the black accent color, the home screen looks beautiful & otherwise it is helpful too since it reduces battery drain, the problem is that when the black accent color is applied, the conversation-textblocks in messaging for both ends becomes black & blends with the 'dark' background and it appears as if the texts are scattered. Even the alphabet menu in Zune-music turns black.
I want to write an application that will allow the phone to apply black as an accent color only to the start screen and other controls such as textblocks, texts, should not be affected by this 'black' accent.
How can I start with this project?
How can I override system colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible because you are asking to set the accent color to black and then complain about the accent color being black.

In the apps that have the unreadable text, the designers used the accent color, so if you change the accent color, you will change those texts.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.
My doubt is can I make everything (except the start screen) that depends on the accent color independent? I want my application to set colors to each control independently.
For example - 
Set color of home screen = 'black'
Set color of all textblocks = 'blue'.
The phone's theme should no more be under control of 'Settings > Theme > Accent color'

Comment: No that isn't possible either. I have nowhere encountered any special settings that a developer could for the start screen.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for several reasons. First of all, your application is running in a sandbox with limited access to the OS. This means that it cannot affect any of the operating system components without having an explicit action from the user.

For example, you can open the WiFi settings, but not turn them on or off directly from your application. Same applies to accent colors. The settings you are talking about are OEM-bound, which means that those are system-wide and are not changeable from any third-party application.